# problems creating an excel file with Java

Tags: java, excel, windows, file

I have a unique problem (or maybe not).

We have a tool on a website provided by someone else.  This tool uploads an excel file, and then processes it.  The excel file has columns and values, and certain columns must be there.  The columns and values cannot be verified unless the file is uploaded.  That is a successful upload must happen before any data (columns, etc) is analyzed.

People generally create the excel file using excel and fill in the values, and that works fine.  This, of course, cannot be done with automation, as the values will change each test.  So I use Java to create the file as it should appear (Windows 10).

```
    // This will be a List of lists.  Outer list is an excel row and it contains cell values.
    // I will not list the code where I populate this list because it may be superfluous to
    // my question, but believe me, I do
    List<List<String>> rowsList = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    ...
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(sheetName);

    for (int rn = 0; rn < rowsList.size(); rn++) {
        List<String> rowData = rowsList.get(rn);
        if (rowData.size() > 0) {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) rn);
            for (int cn = 0; cn < rowData.size(); cn++) {
                String val = rowData.get(cn);
                XSSFCell theCell = row.createCell(cn);
                theCell.setCellValue(val);
            }
        }
    }

    // fileName is the passed in name of the excel file to create
    try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName);) {
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        workbook.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

When I try to upload, it says "upload failed".  I examine the file using excel, and it looks fine, but still I get the problem.  Now here is the interesting part.  I looked at the file again with Excel, made NO changes, but out of habit did a CTRL-S (to save).  Then, when I demoed to someone how it was not uploading, it uploaded fine.

So, I think to save from Excel must have done something that I neglected to / forgot to do in my code, but I am not sure what.  I asked to look at the tool providers' log files to see what the error could be, but they would not let me.

So, somehow when a file is created with Java as above a step or something must be missing, that saving in Excel adds, but I cannot figure it out?

I don't think I can divulge the contents of the Excel file as it is company proprietary, but it is a row of column names, and a corresponding row of text values.

Comment: Please mention/tag the library you are using to generate the Excel file and its version.

Comment: Is it an `.xls` file or an `.xlsx` file? The latter is actually a `.zip` file and you can unpack the one that doesn't work and the one that does and compare them in detail to see what is different.

Comment: yes it is xlsx.  Hold on.  org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel

Comment: I took one and changed the extension to zip (despite Bill Gaite's warnings not to) and I could unzip it.  There are a lot of files.  Any suggestions which to check?

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _When I try to upload, it says "upload failed"._ Are you trying to upload the file from Java code?

Comment: yes, via a website.  I assume it is Java but I don't have access.  I actually came up with a workaround where I take an excel sheet created with excel, and just overwrite the values in two cells.  (Make a copy first).  That works. However, the above may still be needed in the future

Comment: Have you tried to compare (on file/zip level) the Java created Excel file with the one out only open in Excel and fill out some values? Also check the template Excel file for hidden sheets, special formulas and so on the server may expect.

Comment: I did unzip each and compare files and it looks like a lot of differences.  I am not sure which are important